# How to click on a dynamically created link to then create a new dynamic page from that link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, dom-manipulation

I wrote an custom API(node.js app) that gets the info about the blogs from medium.com, right now there is

1. the author/main pic of the article,
2. title,
3. link to the article on medium.com(redundant),
4. the entire article text, in the JSON output.

**Sample API/JSON:**

```
{
"img": [
"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/42/Blog_%281%29.jpg"
],
"title": [
"The old and the new or not so new: Java vs JavaScript"
],
"link": [
"https://medium.com/@aki9154/the-old-and-the-new-or-not-so-new-java-vs-javascript-760f84e87610?source=rss-887f1b1ddb75------2"
],
"desc": [
"<p>It’s funny how the name JavaScript makes you believe that it is somehow..."
]
}
```

Then i am polling this API/JSON and spitting out the output in a thumbnail format, basic html for now(no design/CSS).

**Where i am stuck is when a user clicks on a thumbnail and i need to make sure that i display the correct article?!**

For which i need to display a new page when the thumbnail/article is clicked, i can use #4 from JSON above as an output for that dynamically created new page and put it out nicely)

The issue that i am facing now is how to dynamically produce the correct article when the dynamically created link is clicked?

Right now nothing happens when i click on the thumbnail and that's what this project link displays...

I did some stackoverflow research and read some jQuery docs(event propagation and more...) and was able to make changes to the index.js, below is how it looks like but nothing works, any help will be appreciated...

**index.js:**

```
$(function () {
  var desc = "";
  function newWin() {
    var w = window.open();
     $(w.document.body).html('<p>'+desc+'</p>');
   }
    var $content = $('.cards-in-grid');
    var url = 'link-for private use now';
    $.get(url, function (response) {
      var output = '';
      console.log(response);
      $.each(response, function (k, item) {
      title = item.title;
      var author = item.img;
      desc = item.desc;
      output += '<li><img src="'+author+'" alt=""><h2>' + title + '</h2></li>';
      $(".cards-in-grid ul").on("click", "li", function(){
        newWin;
      });
      return k;
    });
    $content.html(output);
   });
 });
```

Comment: You code looks good .But  Add $(w.document.body).append($content); Another think is that you should check the currect url and check for response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`

```
$(function () {
    var $content = $('.cards-in-grid');
    var url = 'link-for private use now';
    $.get(url, function (response) {
      var output = '';
      var list = "li";
      $.each(response, function (k, item) {
        var listNum = list+k;
        var idy = "#"+listNum;
        var desc = "";
        title = item.title;
        var author = item.img;
        desc = item.desc;
        //GIVE ID to each LI using a variable
        output += '<li id="'+listNum+'"><img src="'+author+'" alt=""><h2>' + 
        title + '</h2></li>';
        $content.html(output); 
        $content.on("click",idy, function(){
          var w = window.open();
          $(w.document.body).html('<p>'+desc+'</p>');
        });
        return k;
      });
    });
 });
```

*This worked perfectly, some thinking and pondering and was able to make it work!!*
*Kindly Upvote the answer, if it helped you! Thanks!*